# How to join two tables on fields that are not formatted the same

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables containing a string field that in one table is six bytes long, and in the other table is seven bytes long, because of the insertion of a hyphen between the first two bytes and the last four bytes.  The two fields look like this:  AB1234 and AB-1234.  I tried a join like this:

```
    FROM       TableA ta
    INNER JOIN TableB tb ON Left(ta.fld, 2) + '-' + Mid(ta.fld, 3) = tb.fld
```

...and I tried

```
    FROM       TableA ta
    INNER JOIN TableB tb ON Left(ta.fld, 2) = Left(tb.fld, 2) AND Mid(ta.fld, 3) = Mid(tb.fld, 4)
```

...but neither works.  Is there a way to do this with a subquery?  Is there another approach?

Comment: This problem indicates your database has design issues.

Comment: using this type for the function like MID(column_name,start,length)

Comment: `Mid("AB-1234", 3)` = `-1234`. You'd need `Start = 4`.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `REPLACE` to remove the dash before comparing:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.fld = REPLACE(b.fld, "_", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RIGHT instead of MID

```
Left(ta.fld, 2) + '-' + RIGHT(ta.fld, 4) = tb.fld
```